# problems with text parsing using preg_split

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I write some easy parser for my page and have some problem with it.

HTML text:

```
<p>some text</p><p>another text</p>
```

If I try use something like:

```
preg_split("#<p>#",$string);
```

I have a result without `<p>`, and this is very very bad. (only `</p>` exist)

Maybe I can split this string to array, but don't remove `</p>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like Ivan said, you should use `(?=<p>)`. Just wanted to add that you can use

```
var $Paragraphs = array_filter(preg_split("/(?=<p>)/", "<p>some text</p><p>another text</p>"));
```

Which will be:

```
[1] => <p>some text</p>
[2] => <p>another text</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this construct `(?=<p>)` which is [positive lookahead zero-width assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). This pattern will not consume the text it matches. It just will find the position before `<p>` string. Here is example:

```
preg_split("#(?=<p>)#",$string);
```